# MYSQL Insert strips backslash escape character from json string

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert data into a mysql database, with the code below.
Problem is, my json code containing the value "R\u00f8nde" is changed to "Ru00f8nde" after I insert it into the database.

What is the best way to avoid this?

```
INSERT INTO jos_payplans_user(user_id, params) VALUES ('24882', '{"modtager":"Anders And","adresse":"Paradisaeblevej 111","postnr":"1234","by":"R\u00f8nde","telefon":"12345678","user_notes":""}')
```

Comment: Properly prepare/bind/escape your values for SQL. [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 0):

In json itself avoid the slashes and insert in db

```
echo json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` foregoes escaping *slashes* (`/`). It has nothing to do with the *backslashes* in the question. It's also rather useless if you already have perfectly valid JSON which contains perfectly valid backslashes.